# Changing HTML <select> Element Using Only HTML/PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve data from a SQL DB when the user types a category ID in to search with. It should then autofill (populate) the html form data with the retrieved data from the row's columns (upon pressing the submit button).

Everything is working properly, but I don't know how to change a dropdown menu

For example:
`<input name="prodname" type="text" value="<?php echo $pName; ?>"/>`

Fills the form value successfully after I press the search(submit) button.

This following code does not change the drop down values at all `(<select> vs <input>)`

`<select name="supplierID" value="<?php $suppID; ?>">`

How can I change the drop down values of a  while only using HTML/PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Loop through the list of values you want to show. For each value, create an HTML `option` element within the `select`.

Comment: I fear that it (showing search results based on userinput value) can not be done only using php and HTML. Since php is compiled at server side. You might want to consider client side scripting like JavaScript.

Comment: You need to set the `selected` attribute on the selected `option` element. Just setting the value of the `select` element won't work IIRC.

Comment: @Kei I believe that's how I have it set up right now, for example: ```<select name="supplierID" value="<?php $suppID; ?>">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>``` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a option in `<select>` tag you need to set `selected` attribute to that option. The following code may help you to understand.

```
<select name="supplierID">
    <option value="1" <?php if($suppID == 1) echo 'selected'; ?> >1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($suppID == 2) echo 'selected'; ?> >2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($suppID == 3) echo 'selected'; ?> >3</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($suppID == 4) echo 'selected'; ?> >4</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To select the values in drop down, the `selected` attribute is required. You may check with the code below:

```
<select name="supplierID">
  <option value="1" <?php if($id == 1) echo "selected"; ?>> A </option>
  <option value="2" <?php if($id == 2) echo "selected"; ?>> B </option>        
  <option value="3" <?php if($id == 3) echo "selected"; ?>> C </option>
</select>
```